# Montar menu dinâmico

Tags: array, angular

Tenho o seguinte array

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de ciar um menu com submenu dinâmico, mais ou  menos como esse aqui

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei fazer dessa maneira

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree" *ngIf="menuArray">
        <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>

        <ng-container *ngFor="let menu of menuArray ">

            <li *ngIf="menu.submenu; else itemMenu" class="treeview">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa {{ menu.logo }}"></i><span>{{ menu.menu }}</span>
                <span class="pull-right-container">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <ng-template #itemMenu>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa {{ menu.logo }}"></i><span>{{ menu.menu }}</span>                               
                </a>
              </li>   
            </ng-template>
        </ng-container>
 </ul>
```

Mas está dando a seguinte mensagem no console
**

> core.js:1673 ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only
>   arrays and iterables are allowed

**

No meu componente eu inicializo o meu array

```
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
  menuArray = []
  constructor(private loginService: LoginService) {

   }
```

Depois pego os dados do banco assim:

```
 getMenuArray(){
    this.loginService.menu( window.sessionStorage.getItem('id') )
                     .subscribe( menu => {
                       this.menuArray = menu
                       console.log('menu', menu)

                      }) 

  }
```

Ou tem como eu montar o menu no component.ts e depois jogar na página?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse erro é causado por que o ngFor espera um Array e a sua api está retornando um objeto.

Referência https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38216857/error-trying-to-diff-object-object

Comment: Não é que começou a dar certo? Lá no meu componente eu mudei disso `this.menuArray = menu` para isso `this.menuArray = menu.array` e apareceu os menus, agora vou trabalhar nos submenus